# Is this program sending passwords over the internet in the clear?

Tags: python, security, ofx

[ofxclient](https://github.com/captin411/ofxclient) looks like a full featured [ofx](http://www.ofx.org/DownloadPage/Downloads.aspx) library for interacting with your bank.  But [when you initially check your username and password](http://captin411.github.io/ofxclient/usage.html#adding-accounts) it [looks like you're sending an http request containing your password](https://github.com/captin411/ofxclient/blob/master/ofxclient/client.py#L127) directly to the bank.  It seems unlikely your bank would let you do that, so I expect I'm not understanding this code.

What's going on?  Is there something you're supposed to do to put this under SSL?

Comment: It looks like it's using [HTTPS](https://github.com/captin411/ofxclient/blob/master/ofxclient/client.py#L5)

Comment: I didn't notice that when I just followed execution with `pdb`.  Thanks.  Why not post as an answer which I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's using [HTTPS](https://github.com/captin411/ofxclient/blob/master/ofxclient/client.py#L5) for the encryption.